# SurveyJS extension for TYPO3 CMS. Where to start? Or is the native form framework sufficient?

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, surveyjs, typo3-form

I would like to seamlessly integrate [SurveyJS](https://surveyjs.io/) in TYPO3 CMS, but could not find an existing extension. Did anyone already start a project like that? I only found a post from 2018 in [answerdesk.io](https://surveyjs.answerdesk.io/ticket/details/t852/plugin-for-typo3).

Or would it be easier to extend the native form extension in TYPO3 v10?
(Meanwhile I can answer that myself with NO. The form editor has still no gui to define conditions.)

Requirements for our use case:

- Fully integrate SurveyJS in TYPO3 (no programming or html elements needed for editors).
- Store survey jsons in database and optionally (because of licences) include the SurveyJS Creator in TYPO3.
- A TYPO3 plugin to display a survey on your page.
- Extend SurveyJS Creator to be able to add TYPO3 contents as "[Custom Widgets](https://surveyjs.io/Examples/Survey-Creator/?id=customwidgets)" (using the TYPO3 Element Browser to select the content elements or files).
- Extend SurveyJS Player to display these TYPO3 elements in the survey.
- Possibility of using "finishers" (would it be possible to use the form finishers) to store the data to TYPO3 database or send an email.

So my questions are:

- Is there already a running project on this to join?
- Any help or ideas to start this in TYPO3 (maybe an existing extension that uses the Element Browser in custom HTML / JS or uses the finishers from TYPO3 forms).

Comment: This repo https://github.com/surveyjs/surveyjs-wordpress shows how to integrate SurveyJS Libraries with Wordpress. It isn't an answer on your question but I hope can help you.

Comment: @tsv Thank you for your input. I will have a look at your WP plugin. It is what I am looking for in TYPO3 except that we need widgets for TYPO3 elements in addition.

Comment: if you start to work on your extension we could advise you. You can write us directly at https://surveyjs.answerdesk.io/ or email to support@surveyjs.io

Comment: @TSV Sounds great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you need to achieve. If you want to use surveyJS, you need to load that with their API like https://surveyjs.io/Help/Api/GET-api-Survey-getSurvey_surveyId?apiType=public&renderType=desktop.

If you want to use the form extension, I don't see a way to combine this with this external service but you can use conditions as well. This works since version 10, check out https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/master/en-us/I/Concepts/Variants/Index.html

---

I don't know any extensions which integrates SurveyJS, so I suggest you start it and maybe people join. I propose registering the extension key and do the development in public so people can find it.

Comment: SurveyJS can work isolated. It doesn't require connection to SurveyJS Service. It's a set of client-side JavaScript libraries initialized by survey JSON description. This description can be stored anywhere according the requirements. Survey result is also a JSON object. And can be stored in any appropriate database. The original question is too broad. The answer will depend on what @Ludwig want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I want to seamlessly integrate SurveyJS into TYPO3. So build an extension that has a backend module that shows me the available surveys. A click on the edit icon will open the Survey Creator within TYPO3, having extra widgets to include TYO3 content elements. Then a plugin will be needed that lets me select the desired survey from the existing ones. I will update my question to be more precise.